# Phusion Passenger preloader error nginx

Tags: ruby, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

I'd like to thank you in advance for helping me out with this.
I am going mad here trying to figure out what is wrong with phusion passenger or my rails app.

I have done a lot of googling as well as read everything on https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Debugging-application-startup-problems but i still can not seem to figure out what the problem is.

I have included where i think the problem lies but the full error can be accessed at www.malikhandaan.com.

Thank you so much for helping, in advance.

(I am newbie at rails, this is my first app deploy with nginx)

```
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------     
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'  
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>' 
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:153:in `<module:App>' 
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:108:in `preload_app' 
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:108:in `eval' config.ru:1:in 
`<main>' config.ru:1:in `new' /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/rack-
1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize' /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-
p353/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval' config.ru:3:in `block in 
<main>' config.ru:3:in `require' 
/usr/share/nginx/www/malikhandaan/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>' 
/usr/share/nginx/www/malikhandaan/config/environment.rb:2:in `require' 
/usr/share/nginx/www/malikhandaan/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>' 
/usr/share/nginx/www/malikhandaan/config/application.rb:3:in `require' 
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `<top 
(required)>' /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-
4.0.2/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `require' /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-
p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails.rb:9:in `<top (required)>' 
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails.rb:9:in `require' 
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in 
`<top (required)>' /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-
4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:4:in `require' /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-
p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' 
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in 
`require' /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-
4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>' /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-
p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `require' 
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-
4.0.2/lib/rails/configuration.rb:3:in `<top (required)>' /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-
2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/configuration.rb:3:in `require' 
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-
4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:11:in `<top (required)>' 
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-
4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:11:in `require' /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-
2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb:3:in 
`<top (required)>' /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-
4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb:3:in `require' 
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json.rb:54:in `<top 
(required)>' /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json.rb:58:in 
`<module:JSON>' /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json.rb:58:in 
`require' /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:9:in 
`<top (required)>' /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/json-
1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:12:in `<module:JSON>' /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-
p353/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext.rb:17:in `<module:Ext>' /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-
2.0.0-p353/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `generator=' 
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:67:in `new' 
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:67:in 
`initialize' 


[NOTE] You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries. 
Bug reports are welcome. For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: so i looked over it again and i saw this 
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/common.rb:67: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: That is a problem in Ruby, not in Passenger. See the last few lines of messages.

Comment: Thanks Hongli I appreciate your response...yeah i am looking into that right now...i think the json gem is messed up

Answer (score 0):

After much research and plugin all night at this i found that ruby-2.0.0 seems to have this error as i downgraded to ruby-1.9.3 the problem was resolved.....i moved from one problem to another...at least i am past this one. :)

Hope this helps any newbie to rails.